# Output in a different workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I've created a tool and the below macro copies all .csv files into a excel sheet. I want the data to be copied to the "Consol.xlsx" file that I created. The current code copies the data in the tool not the "Consol.xlsx" file. I am unable to update the code so that the data gets copied correctly.

Below is my code:

```
Sub Button_click2()
Call AddNew
Call ImportCSVsWithReference
End Sub

Sub AddNew()
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Dim thisWb As Workbook
    Set thisWb = ActiveWorkbook
    Workbooks.Add
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=thisWb.path & "\Consol.xlsx"
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub


Sub ImportCSV()

   Dim strSourcePath As String
   Dim strDestPath As String
   Dim strFile As String
   Dim strData As String
   Dim x As Variant
   Dim Cnt As Long
   Dim r As Long
   Dim c As Long

   Application.ScreenUpdating = False

   'Change the path to the source folder accordingly
   strSourcePath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.path

   If Right(strSourcePath, 1) <> "\" Then strSourcePath = strSourcePath & "\"

   'Change the path to the destination folder accordingly
   strDestPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.path

   If Right(strDestPath, 1) <> "\" Then strDestPath = strDestPath & "\"

   strFile = Dir(strSourcePath & "*.csv")

   Do While Len(strFile) > 0
       Cnt = Cnt + 1
       r = Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
       Open strSourcePath & strFile For Input As #1
           Do Until EOF(1)
               Line Input #1, strData
               x = Split(strData, ",")
               For c = 0 To UBound(x)
                   Cells(r, c + 1).Value = Trim(x(c))
               Next c
               r = r + 1
           Loop
       Close #1
       Name strSourcePath & strFile As strDestPath & strFile
       strFile = Dir
   Loop

   Application.ScreenUpdating = True

   If Cnt = 0 Then _
       MsgBox "No CSV files were found...", vbExclamation

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Well it looks like you've got both of the pieces there. Your first subroutine saves a blank workbook called consol.xlsx.

Then, your second subroutine loops through the directory, opens each csv file, and copes it to some unspecified range.

What I would insert before your loop is:

```
Set wbkConsol = Workbooks.Open(thisWorkbook.path & "\Consol.xlsx")
```

Then, during your loop over the CSV files:

```
strFile = Dir(strSourcePath & "*.csv")
Do While Len(strFile) > 0
   Cnt = Cnt + 1
   r = Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
   Open strSourcePath & strFile For Input As #1
       Do Until EOF(1)
           Line Input #1, strData
           ' Set wshAdd = wbkConsol.Worksheets.Add() ' New ws in wbk
           ' wshAdd.Name = left(strFile, 31) ' First 31-chars of filename.
           x = Split(strData, ",")
           For c = 0 To UBound(x)
               wshAdd.Cells(r, c + 1).Value = Trim(x(c))
           Next c
           r = r + 1
       Loop
   Close #1
   Name strSourcePath & strFile As strDestPath & strFile
   strFile = Dir()
Loop
```

As an added note: you could pass your workbook from your first sub to the second sub, by reference. That way, you won't have to open it up again. This would be by combining the button click into just a single command.

```
Sub1()
      wbkConsol = workbooks.Add
      Call sub2(wbkConsol)
End sub
```

Comment: I got an error saying object variable or With block variable not set at wshadd.cells

How do i resolved this?

Comment: Ah, sorry, you may want to ensure that you have un-commented the lines.

Comment: My code worked well when I put Set wbkConsol = Workbooks.Open(thisWorkbook.path & "\Consol.xlsx")

However, there excel sheet has double quotes. How do I get rid of this text qualifier?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You know what, this could likely be solved by a simple replace. I take it you're having this issue at the line with wshAdd.Name, right? Just wrap the left(strFile, 31) like so: Replace(left(strFile, 31), """, ""). Shown in the link here: https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/replace_vba.php